# Does any accessible model category come from an algebraic model category?

Tags: ct.category-theory, model-categories

I read in [nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/algebraic+model+category) : *Every [cofibrantly generated model category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/cofibrantly+generated+model+category) structure can be lifted to that of an [algebraic model category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/algebraic+model+category). It is not clear whether or not this is true for any [accessible model category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/accessible+model+category)*. Is there any progress since the most recent edit of this page (January 17, 2019) ?

Comment: The page on accessible model categories does claim that they are always algebraic, with a proof sketch on the page on accessible wfs's at https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/accessible+weak+factorization+system . They use a result by Rosicky that every accessible wfs on a locally presentable category is cofibrantly generated. Maybe it depends on whether local presentability is included in the definition of accessible?

Comment: @aws I am a bit confused. The page claims that accessible weak factorization systems can be enhanced to algebraic weak factorization systems. But the notion of algebraic model category is a little bit more strong: there must be a morphism of algebraic weak factorization systems. Is it obvious that it exists ?

Comment: That also follows from the model structure being cofibrantly generated. You can choose the generating cofibrations so that the generating trivial cofibrations are a subcategory (if that isn't true already), and it follows that there is a morphism of awfs's. See Remark 3.7 in Riehl, Algebraic model structures https://arxiv.org/pdf/0910.2733.pdf .

Comment: @aws : I don't see how this answer the question: We know that every accessible wfs can be cofibrantly generated in the algebraic sense, but it is not cofibrantly generated in the usual sense, so the remark in Riehl's paper do not applies to this case. What we need to answer the question is to refine Rosicky's results to show that given any accessible wfs (L,R) and some small double category of 'cofibrations' C with the LLP against all maps in R, one can find a generating double category for (L,R) that contains C. I'm not familiar enough with Rosicky's result to know if this is clear or not.

Comment: Surely Riehl's argument still works? You have a generating diagram $D : J \to \mathcal{M}^\to$ for cofibrations and a generating diagram $E : I \to \mathcal{M}^\to$ for trivial cofibrations. The new generating diagram for cofibrations is the coproduct $D + E : J + I \to \mathcal{M}^\to$. This changes the structured notion of trivial fibration, but the underlying class of maps will be the same.

Comment: @aws : first let me clarify: I tend to believe you are right, but because all the expert have been very careful with this question (e.g. just below the remark 3.7 in Riehl paper you mentioned above, th 3.8 is making the assumption that the generating cofibrations are a set and not a categories, which seems unatural in this paper...) , and I haven't really thought about it I'm starting with the assumption that there is a problem. What I see could go wrong in your argument is that you are forgetting closure under retract: we know that every trivial fibration is a retract of map...

Comment: ... with the RLP against J and a retract of a map with the RLP against I (because it is also a fibration), but how do you know it is also a retract of map with both RLP ? I guess you can do something using the small object argument to construct such a map and maybe your argument works.... but some work is required and as it seems that everybody that have thought seriously about it seem to have doubts, I wouldn't consider this an answer yet

Comment: I'll write up something more detailed as an answer, but retract closure isn't a problem in this case because it's Garner's original definition with categories, not the Bourke-Garner definition with double categories (Lemma 2.30 in Riehl's paper).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For reference, here is a more detailed version of Riehl's argument.

**Definition 1** (Garner, [*Understanding the small object argument*](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10485-008-9137-4), Proposition 3.8) Let $J$ be a category and $D \colon J \to \mathcal{M}^\to$ a functor. Let $f \colon X \to Y$ be a map in $\mathcal{M}$. A *lifting structure* of $f$ against $D$ consists of a choice of diagonal lift for each object $j$ of $J$ and lifting problem of $D(j)$ against $f$, which is compatible with the morphisms in $J$.

**Theorem 2** (Garner, [*Understanding the small object argument*](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10485-008-9137-4), Theorem 4.4) Suppose $\mathcal{M}$ is locally presentable. Let $J$ be a small category and $D \colon J \to \mathcal{M}$ a functor. Then there is an algebraic weak factorisation system $(L, R)$ on $\mathcal{M}$ such that $R$-algebra structures on a map $f$ correspond precisely to lifting structures of $f$ against $D$. We say that $(L, R)$ is *algebraically cofibrantly generated by $D$*.

**Lemma 3** Let $D \colon I \to \mathcal{M}$ and $E \colon J \to \mathcal{M}$. Then lifting structures of $f$ against the coproduct $D + E \colon I + J \to \mathcal{M}^\to$ correspond precisely to pairs of lifting structures against $D$ and against $E$.

**Proof** It is obvious how to define the lifting structure against $D + E$, so we just have to check that it satisfies naturality for morphisms in $I + J$. However, the coproduct in categories $I + J$ is disjoint, in the sense that there are no maps $\sigma \colon i \to j$ where $i$ lies in the $I$ component and $j$ in the $J$ component, so naturality does follow from naturality for the lifting structures against $D$ and against $E$.

**Theorem 4** (Rosický, [*Accessible model categories*](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10485-015-9419-6), Theorem 4.3) Suppose that $\mathcal{M}$ is locally presentable and $(\mathcal{L}, \mathcal{R})$ is an accessible wfs. Then there is a small category $I$ and a functor $D \colon I \to \mathcal{M}^\to$ such that $\mathcal{R}$ is precisely the class of maps admitting a lifting structure against $D$.

Note in particular that the class of maps admitting a lifting structure against $D$ is closed under retracts (see also Remark 3.4 in Rosický, and Lemma 2.30 in Riehl).

**Lemma 5** Let $\mathcal{M}$ be locally presentable and $I$ and $J$ small. Suppose we are given functors $D \colon I \to \mathcal{M}^\to$ and $E \colon J \to \mathcal{M}^\to$ together with a functor $F \colon I \to J$ making a commutative triangle. Then there is a morphism of algebraic weak factorisation systems from the awfs cofibrantly generated by $D$ to the awfs cofibrantly generated by $E$.

**Proof** As Riehl remarks in [*Algebraic model structures*](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0910.2733.pdf), this follows from freeness. There is another way to phrase this using reflections. Garner's argument, as presented in [*Understanding the small object argument*](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10485-008-9137-4) in fact produces reflections for a canonical functor $\mathbf{AWFS}(\mathcal{M}) \to \mathbf{CAT}/\mathcal{M}^\to$. In general, given a functor $G \colon \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{D}$, a reflection of an object $D \in \mathcal{D}$ is an initial object of the comma category $(D \downarrow G)$. Given a morphism between two objects $D \to D'$ in $\mathcal{D}$, there is a unique map between the components of their reflections in $\mathcal{C}$ making a commutative square. Applying to this special case, any morphism in $\mathbf{CAT}/\mathcal{M}^\to$ gives rise to a morphism between reflections in $\mathbf{AWFS}(\mathcal{M})$.

**Theorem 6** Let $\mathcal{M}$ be locally presentable and $(\mathcal{C}, \mathcal{W}, \mathcal{F})$ an accessible model structure on $\mathcal{M}$. Then there is an algebraic model structure $\xi \colon (C, F^t) \to (C^t, F)$ on $\mathcal{M}$, where the class of maps admitting $F$-algebra structure is precisely $\mathcal{F}$ and the class of maps admitting $F^t$-algebra structure is precisely $\mathcal{F} \cap \mathcal{W}$.

**Proof** By Theorem 4, there are diagrams $D \colon I \to \mathcal{M}^\to$ and $E \colon J \to \mathcal{M}^\to$, with $I, J$ small categories such that $\mathcal{F}$ is the class of maps admitting a lifting structure against $D$ and $\mathcal{F}^t := \mathcal{F} \cap \mathcal{W}$ is the class of maps admitting a lifting structure against $E$. We take $(C^t, F)$ to be the awfs cofibrantly generated by $D$ and take $(C, F^t)$ to be the awfs cofibrantly generated by $D + E \colon I + J \to \mathcal{M}^\to$. By Lemma 5, the inclusion $D \to D + E$ induces a morphism of awfs's $\xi \colon (C^t, F) \to (C, F^t)$. By Theorems 2 and 4, $\mathcal{F}$ is precisely the class of maps admitting $F$-algebra structure. Now let $g$ be a map in $\mathcal{F}^t$. Then it also lies in $\mathcal{F}$, and so by Theorem 4 it admits lifting structures against both $D$ and $E$. Hence by Lemma 3 it admits a lifting structure against $D + E$. Hence it admits $F^t$-algebra structure by Theorem 2. The converse is straightforward using Theorem 2 again. Hence the wfs underlying $(C, F^t)$ is precisely $(\mathcal{C}, \mathcal{F}^t)$. We have now shown that the model structure underlying the algebraic model structure $\xi$ is precisely $(\mathcal{C}, \mathcal{W}, \mathcal{F})$.